# Want to add a menu and create a navigation in pages with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

Following is a HTML file which is used to enter a movie title and search results are displayed. 
I need a menu to this page, which which redirect to different pages and those pages will like about us, featured films, search films.

I want to use ngRoute angular feature to route to these pages.

Below is my html and JS, Although the JS file currently does the functionality of fetching a movie searched for from OMDB API. I want to add ngroute in my JS

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>


  <!-- SPELLS -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
   <!-- SCROLLS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" />

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.1/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <title>Movie Search | OMDb API</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="OMDbAPISearch">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="searchMovies">

    <h1>Search a Movie Title Below</h1>
    <p>This application utilizes OMDb API data for all results (<a href="http://www.omdbapi.com" target="_blank">http://www.omdbapi.com</a>)</p>
    <form>
      <div class="search">
       <input id="theSearch" ng-model="searchparam" placeholder="movie name" type="text" ngTrim="true" />
       <button ng-click="fetch()">Search</button>
       <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
    </form>

    <div class="results">

      <div class="result" movie-srch-results ng-repeat="movie in movieResults"></div>

    </div>
    <div class="noResults"></div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to introduce a menu, and use ngRoute: This is my `style.js`
I want to have a menu called pages with options like about Us , features films etc.

Please help me in introducing ngroute in my js file.

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('OMDbAPISearch', [])
    .controller('searchMovies', ['$scope', '$http',
      function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.method = 'GET';
        $scope.fetch = function() {
          if ($scope.searchparam) {
            $scope.url = 'https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=' + $scope.searchparam + '&type=movie&r=json';
            $http({
              method: $scope.method,
              url: $scope.url
            }).
            then(function(response) {
              if (response.data.Response) {
                // success
                $('.results').css('display', 'block');
                $('.noResults').css('display', 'none');
                var theSrchResults = response.data["Search"];
                angular.forEach(theSrchResults, function(obj) {
                  // loop through each movie, and pull the details using the IMDB ID
                  $http({
                    method: $scope.method,
                    url: 'https://www.omdbapi.com/?i=' + obj.imdbID + '&plot=full&r=json&tomatoes=true'
                  }).
                  then(function(response) {
                    // extend the details to the parent
                    obj.details = response.data;
                  });
                });
                $scope.movieResults = theSrchResults;
              } else {
                //error, movie not found
                console.log("not found");
                $('.results').css('display', 'none');
                $('.noResults').css('display', 'block');
                $('.noResults').html("<strong>No results found.</strong>");
              }
            }, function(response) {
              console.log("failure");
              $('.results').css('display', 'none');
              $('.noResults').css('display', 'block');
              $('.noResults').html("<strong>Network or data error, please try again.</strong>");
            });
          } else {
            // no input value
            $('.results').css('display', 'none');
            $('.noResults').css('display', 'none');
            $('#theSearch').fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
          }
        };
      }
    ])
    .directive('movieSrchResults', function() {
      return {
        templateUrl: 'movieResults.html'
      };
    });
})(window.angular);
```

Here is my [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/b7HFrctdwqYYsybYHTPy)
but how do I add ngRoute in my JS file?

Comment: You can refer to their documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

And easy example here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#examples

Comment: Hi Pal, I am not able to edit my js file, it is already calling the main controller which does the function of searching the move. How should i add a function for routing in the same js file

Comment: I don't know what you mean by cannot edit js file. but I've updated your plnkr and it has routing now: https://plnkr.co/edit/iibXLu0DAW1qa6LreDLG?p=info

Comment: for some reason it is not working on browsers, i tried running on chrome and mozilla....https://plnkr.co/edit/gyqCl3tLgRhHmaTwe6fq?p=preview....It is not finding any local files i have every file in place

Comment: @PalSingh i tried running this plunkr....plnkr.co/edit/iibXLu0DAW1qa6LreDLG?p=info  the one you sent...when i go to home /contact/ about us page...it says file not found on both mozilla and chrome browsers

Comment: @PalSingh please help.... 
plnkr.co/edit/gyqCl3tLgRhHmaTwe6fq  it says page not found when i navigate

Comment: It works completely fine for me. This is the URL `https://plnkr.co/edit/iibXLu0DAW1qa6LreDLG?p=preview`

Answer (score 0):

just update your line `angular.module('OMDbAPISearch', [])` to `angular.module('OMDbAPISearch', ['ngRoute'])` and add lines as i have written just below of it.

```
angular.module('OMDbAPISearch', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider,$httpProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider
    .when('/',{
        templateUrl:  'home.html'
    })
    .when('/home',{
        templateUrl: 'home.html'
    })
    .when('/about',{
        templateUrl: 'about.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
    redirectTo: "/"
    });
})
```